# Parsing json to php in httpful from laravel eloquent

Tags: php, json, api, rest, parsing

I have this JSON data. How do you parse this with httpful? or in just plain PHP?

I want to be able to display something like

```
Name: John Doe |
Phone: 0987654321 |
Email: john@doe.com |
Friend's Name: Jane Doe

Name: Rye Dale | 
Phone: 0987654321 | 
Email: rye@dale.com | 
Friend's Name: John Dale
```

How do I properly parse this?

```
"group":[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Doe",
        "phoneNumber":"0987654321",
        "email":"john@doe.com",
        "friend":
            {
                "firstName":"Jane",
                "lastName":"Doe",
            }
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "firstName":"Rye",
        "lastName":"Dale",
        "phoneNumber":"0123456789",
        "email":"rye@dale.com",
        "friend":
            {
                "firstName":"John",
                "lastName":"Dale",
            }
    }
]
```

Comment: try to research `parse JSON in php` im sure you'll get a lot of hits

Comment: i tried, but i can't find something similar to this format

Comment: start with `json_decode()`

Comment: Very simple if you Google'd :)

Comment: @DavidAlrdrin your json is invalid

Comment: actually i'm trying it using Httpful but it seems like it does not get the friend array with print_r($response->body->group as $group)

Comment: @meda I'm actually using laravel to send it to json and that is the output

Comment: so show the code then

Comment: just showed it below... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it sorted out. thanks for all your help. using httpful, you can parse with this.

```
foreach ($response->body->groups as $group)
{
    echo "id: ". $group->id;
    echo "firstName: ". $group->firstName;
    echo "lastName: ". $group->lastName;
    echo "phoneNumber: ". $leads->phoneNumber;
    echo "email: ". $group->email;
    echo "Friend's Name: ". $group->friend->firstName . $group->friend->lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the laravel eloquent to output to json.

```
$result = Group::with('friends')
->get(array('id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'email'));

return Response::json(array(
    'group' => $result->toArray()),
    200
);
```

Comment: this displays the json structure above. so not sure how to properly format it. The with('friends') generates the structure "friend" inside